# How should i go about building the web based file manager in python

Tags: python, django

I have my desktop and in that i have the virtual machine where i have the django site working.

Now i have the external USB drive connected to the host where i have all the data.

I want to build the web interface for managing the files in that external drive. The main function i want to do is to

1. move the files from one folder to another via web interface
2. have the same folder structure in other folder named Archive so that when i select the folder and click archive then system should move that folder to that location

Can anyone give me some direction on how should i proceed. I don't want the code but just guide lines on how should i approach the problem and tools /packages to use

Comment: As stated, the question is a bit too broad. I'm sure you will get better answers if you narrow it down.

Comment: The main thing which i want to know is moving folders from one location to another with python via web interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving files around over a web interface is essentially the same operation you would perform using the CLI, except that the user running the underlying webserver must have file system permissions to perform the operation.

Look at these modules:

- [shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)
- [path.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py)

They are a level above `os.rename` & company.

Answer (score 0):

since file operations can take quite some time, you should consider using something like [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to do the actual work in the background. This keeps your views fast, so they won't time out if the moving/copying is taking longer.